# Error while trying to import SQL file: 1044 - Access denied

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm currently trying to export from `freehostia` to `000webhost`

Using the following SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wp_blog_versions (
  blog_id bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  db_version varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  last_updated datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (blog_id),
  KEY db_version (db_version)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
MySQL said: Documentation
```

But I get the following error:

> 1044 - Access denied for user 'id3573613_weiwilson1'@'%' to database 'information_schema'

What do I have to do to resolve the 1044 problem?

Comment: Start by tagging the correct dbms. This question is not related to sql server. However, "access denied" is a pretty specific error - the account you are using does not have permission as specified. Go talk to your dba.

Comment: Your user and password can be wrong or your user has no permission to create a table, try create another user and set the right permissions at the cpanel. Next time please: don't say "hi" it is not related to the question, describe what tools and technologies are you using, MySQL for example

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Write minimal code that has this problem. Show us that exact code. Google your error message without your specific names.